# Random unwanted log off in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I installed Jaunty on a pretty old box (1.2 GHZ AMD, ATI 9550, 512MB ram.. ).

Everything went OK, installed printer, emesene, skype, radeon driver, ...

At the end, I copied all music/video files from the windows that was previously installed. OFC, all permissions were set (from NTFS). I can't be sure, but this may be relevant since problem started appearing just after system stopped responding in the middle of the file transfer.

PROBLEM:

System just randomly logs off. In middle of surfing with Firefox or with just terminal working on aptitude. Sometimes programs just closes with no message or whatsoever. Rarely, PC freezes.

I went through dmsg, xsession log and found nothing. I will paste those files if relevant. I also tried disabling screensaver, didn't help.

Does normal user have permission for killing programs and logging off? It may be some plain vanilla virus written by scriptkiddie.

Any idea is welcome, thanks.

**EDIT: looks like that's how X crashes. I will be inspecting X logs.**

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely not a virus written by a scriptkiddie. Viruses are sort of hard to write for *nix (not to say it can't be done). Does it turn off or just log off? If it turns off you might check to see if your computer is overheating.

**Edit:** Try disabling Desktop Effects (Compiz). Ubuntu doesn't want to play nicely with ATI graphics cards. I had a problem with resuming from standby only to find out that Ubuntu was forgetting to tell my screen to turn back on because of my graphic card.

Comment: It just loggs off. I mean, login screen shows. I've been told this is a way how X crashes. I'll inspect into logs later tonight.

Answer (score 2):

its probably overheating! I had the same problem, when temperature got over 70C (coping music from ipod to ntfs partition, firefox, compiz)..

sudo apt-get install sensors

That will show your temp. if its too hot, add a gnome-panel applet that lets you limit the processors frequency. Also, assuming its a laptop, put it on a flat surface... that helps air flow.

my sys:
dell d810, ubuntu 9.10